Incompatible version of Node.js with Windows
I'm encountering an issue when trying to run Node.js on my Windows machine. I receive the following error message:
This version of C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro
Node.js Version:20.14.0
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:
Verified my Windows version and system type
Re-downloaded and re-installed Node.js from the official website.
Checked environment variables and path settings.

Node.js generally aims to maintain compatibility with major operating systems, including Windows. However, there might be specific versions that have issues or are not recommended for certain Windows environments. As of the latest updates:

Older Node.js Versions: Very old versions of Node.js (e.g., versions before 0.12) may not be compatible or may require special workarounds to run on modern Windows systems. These versions are also no longer maintained or supported.

Node.js 4.x: The Node.js 4.x series reached end-of-life in April 2018 and is not recommended for use on any platform, including Windows.

Node.js 8.x: The Node.js 8.x series reached end-of-life in December 2019. It's advisable not to use this version on any platform.

Node.js 9.x and 11.x: These are odd-numbered versions that were never intended for long-term support (LTS). They might have specific compatibility issues and are not recommended for production use on Windows or any other platform.

Latest Versions: While the latest versions of Node.js (e.g., 14.x, 16.x, and 18.x as of mid-2024) generally have good support for Windows, there may be occasional issues with very new releases until they are patched.


Recommendations:

Use LTS Versions: Stick to Long-Term Support (LTS) versions, which are well-tested and have good compatibility with Windows. As of mid-2024, Node.js 16.x and 18.x are good choices.
Check System Requirements: Always check the official Node.js documentation for the system requirements and known issues for the version you plan to use.
Keep Updated: Regularly update Node.js to the latest LTS version to benefit from security patches and improved compatibility.

If you have a specific version in mind or are encountering issues, I can help investigate further.
